# Compute a^2 - 3b in assembly language

Tags: assembly, emu8086

i was studying some assembly language i found out a problem to solve `a^2-3b` where a>=0 and b<=100.

My initial algorithm was

```
mov bl 3b 
mov cl a 
sub cl, bl 
mov dl
```

this is the far i could get. I am stuck with the ascii codes for c and whatever the numbers that would be inputted for a and b. I also couldn't get the a^2 thing. So the codes were like this

```
INCLUDE 'EMU8086.INC'

.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    MSG DB "ENTER 1ST DECIMAL NUMBER: ", 0
    
.CODE
    MOV AX, @DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    
    LEA SI, MSG
    CALL PRINT_STRING
    
    CALL SCAN_NUM     ;CX
    MOV AX,CX         ;1ST INPUT IN AX
    
    CALL PTHIS
    DB 0AH, 0DH, "ENTER 2ND DECIMAL NUMBER: ", 0
    
    CALL SCAN_NUM     ;2ND INPUT IN CX
    
    SUB AX, CX
    
    CALL PTHIS
    DB 0AH, 0DH, 0
    
    ;MOV AX, CX
    CALL PRINT_NUM    ;AX
    
    EXIT:
    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H 
         
    
;.............DEFINE PROCEDURES..........;


DEFINE_PRINT_STRING 
DEFINE_PTHIS
DEFINE_GET_STRING
DEFINE_CLEAR_SCREEN
DEFINE_SCAN_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM
DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS
```

could anyone tell me how to get the square of **a^2** or anyone could solve it by simply telling the equation for **`a^2-3b`**?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To compute the square of a number, use the `imul` or `mul` instruction depending on whether the number is signed or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment 
the number is singed i guess

Comment: @MDNasirulIslam: "where a>=0" implies that `a` is unsigned.

Comment: I think it should be singed where it's been given as a " should be greater or equal to 0 " 
Forgive me if i'm wrong. 
Could you please tell me how to do the **square of a number or a^2**

Comment: @MDNasirulIslam Move the number into the `AX` register.  Then execute these instructions: `cwd` and then `imul ax`.  This leaves the square of the number in `DX:AX`.  You can ignore the content of the `DX` register if you know that the square is going to fit into `AX`.

Comment: Thank you @fuz i'm doing it

Comment: @fuz: `cwd` is not needed before `imul` or `mul`. `(i)mul ax` always computes `ax` times `ax`, the `dx` register is not used as a source.

Comment: @ecm You are of course right.  No idea why I put that in.  Must have been early in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

> ...a problem to solve `a^2-3b` where `a>=0` and `b<=100`.

The constraints `a>=0` and `b<=100` don't tell anything about the numbers involved being **signed** or **unsigned**.

---

**Signed** numbers (16 bit) range from -32768 to 32767 but applying the constraints
*a* ranges from 0 to 32767
*b* ranges from -32768 to 100

```
  mov  ax, 3
  mov  bx, [b]
  imul bx       ; -> DX:AX is 3b == [-98301,300]

  mov  bx, ax
  mov  cx, dx   ; -> CX:BX is 3b == [-98301,300]

  mov  ax, [a]
  imul ax       ; -> DX:AX is a^2 == [0,1073676289]

  sub  ax, bx
  sbb  dx, cx   ; -> DX:AX is a^2-3b == [-300,1073774590]
```

Signed dword integers range from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

---

**Unsigned** numbers (16 bit) range from 0 to 65535 but applying the constraints
*a* ranges from 0 to 65535
*b* ranges from 0 to 100

```
  mov  ax, 3
  mov  bx, [b]
  mul  bx       ; -> DX:AX is 3b == [0,300]

  mov  bx, ax
  mov  cx, dx   ; -> CX:BX is 3b == [0,300]

  mov  ax, [a]
  mul  ax       ; -> DX:AX is a^2 == [0,4294836225]

  sub  ax, bx
  sbb  dx, cx   ; -> DX:AX is a^2-3b == [-300,4294836225]
  jb   Overflow ; (*)
```

Unsigned dword integers range from 0 to 4294967295 (*)